# how to change data sorting in kendo ui donut chart series categoryField?

Tags: kendo-ui, donut-chart

i'm mina.
I would like to specify the order of data in series categoryFiled.
categoryField has received a status value.
status has 0, 1, and 2 status values.
status 0 : disconnct
status 1 : connect
status 2 : running

Can I get the order of 2,1,0 using the sort option?

**this is my code :**

```js
   
var toKorean = (function(){
  var set = {
   "RUNNING" : /*[[#{dashboard.Executing}]]*/,
   "CONNECT" : /*[[#{dashboard.Connect}]]*/,
   "DISCONNECT" : /*[[#{dashboard.Disconnect}]]*/, 

  };
  
  return (function(status){
   
   for(var i in set)
   {
    console.log(status);
    if(i == status)
    {
     return set[i]; 
    }
   }
  })
 })();
  function createChart(type) {
  
        $( "#"+type ).kendoChart({
          transitions: false,
          renderAs: "canvas",
          dataSource: {
                 transport: {
                     read: {
                         url: "dashboard/" + type +".json",
                         dataType: "json"
                     }
                 },
                 schema:{
                  data: function(response){
                   console.log(response);
                   for(i in response)
                   {
                    var status = response[i].status;
                    response[i].status = toKorean(status);
                   }
                   return response;

                  }
                 },
                 sort : {
                   field: "status",
                  
                  },
             },
            
              seriesDefaults: {
                  type: "donut",
                 labels: {
                        visible: true,
                        background: "transparent"
                    },
                    overlay: null
              
              },
              seriesColors:["#fd5a21","#ffde43","#66ccff"],
              series: [{
                  field: "count",
                  categoryField: "status",
                  padding: 0
              }],
              
            
         });
   }
```

Comment: Why don't do it at server side?

Comment: Yes! I got wind of it and solved it on the server side.Thank you so much!